# Prove that $U$ is unitary with respect to the product $P_ {T}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$Hello, everyone$ > I have this problem:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional space and $T$ a positive operator ($V$ has an inner product over $\mathbb{C}$). We say that $T$ is positive if

$T ^ {*}=T$ and $\langle T\alpha,\alpha\rangle >0$  for all $\alpha \neq 0$ on $V$

Let $P_ {T}$ be the inner product over $V$ defined by $ P_ {T} (\alpha, \beta) = \langle T\alpha,\beta \rangle$, $U$ an operator over $V$ and $U ^ {*}$ the adjoint of $U$ relative to the inner product. Prove that $U$ is unitary with respect to the product $P_ {T}$ **if and only if** $U = U ^ {*} TU$.

Can someone help me? I don't understand

Thanks for everything. Have a nice day

Comment: Did you mean $T^\ast=T$ rather than $U^\ast=T$, and $T=U^\ast TU$ instead of $U=U^\ast TU$?

Comment: @user1551      
Did you mean T∗=T rather than U∗=T? Yes sorry I wrote incorrectly :( but T=U∗TU instead of U=U∗TU, I dont kwoon , my problem say this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow definition: $U$ is unitary w.r.t. $P_T$ means $P_T(Ux,Uy)=P_T(x,y)$. Now, express this in terms of the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.

Comment: $U=<T\alpha,\beta>$ but I'm not understanding :(

Comment: @user63192 Not sure how you get that, but for any vectors $\alpha,\beta$, we have, by definition, $P_T(\alpha,\beta)=\langle T\alpha,\beta\rangle$. Put $\alpha=Ux$ and $\beta=Uy$, you get an expression of $P_T(Ux,Uy)$ in terms of the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. And you may note that for any linear operator $L$ defined on $V$ and any two $z,w\in V$, we have $\langle z,Lw\rangle=\langle L^\ast z,w\rangle$.

Comment: @user1551 The difficult part is to prove the converse , i.e. if $U$ is unitary w.r.t. $p_T$, then $T=U^*TU$, do you have any ideas how to get that ?

Comment: @the8thone What difficulty did you experience? The proof should be a straightforward one-liner.

Comment: @user1551 If $T=U^*TU$, then $U$ preserves the inner product $p_T$. $$p_T(U\alpha|U\beta)=
(TU\alpha|U\beta)=(U^*TU\alpha|\beta)=(T\alpha|\beta)
=p_T(\alpha|\beta)$$ Therefore $U$ is unitary w.r.t $p_T$.

Comment: @user1551 But for the converse, I do not know what is the adjoint of $ U$ w.r.t the inner product $p_T$, let's denote this adjoint by $U_p$, the the following must hold for all $\alpha, \beta \in V$ $$p_T(U\alpha,\beta)=p_T(\alpha,U_p \beta)$$ then $$p_T(U\alpha,\beta)=(TU\alpha|\beta)=(\alpha|U^*T^* \beta)=(T^{-1}T\alpha|U^*T^*\beta)=(T\alpha|(T^*)^{-1}U^*T^*\beta)=p_T(\alpha,(T^*)^{-1}U^*T^*\beta)$$ Hence by uniqueness of the adjoint operator $U_p=(T^*)^{-1}U^*T^*$ But do we know that $T$ is invertible ?

Comment: @the8thone No, $U^\ast$ is the adjoint of $U$ w.r.t. the original inner product on $V$, not the adjoint of $U$ w.r.t. $P_T$. The question does not state this clearly, but if $U^\ast$ means the adjoint of $U$ w.r.t. $P_T$, then the statement it seeks to prove does not necessarily hold. At any rate, since $T$ is a positive operator, it must be invertible, or else $P_T$ would fail to be an inner product, but this is irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @user1551 well, I do not see the point of your comment, Because I interpreted $U^*$ as the adjoint of $U$ w.r.t (|) , not $p_T$ ! If $T$ is a _strictly positive_ operator (i.e. $(T\alpha|\alpha)>0$ for all $\alpha\neq 0$) then I see why $T$ must be invertible, because if $T$ is singular, then there exists $\alpha\neq 0$ such that $T\alpha=0$, but $(T\alpha|\alpha)=0$ which is a contradiction. Can you please explain why a positive operator (i.e. $(T\alpha|\alpha) \geq 0$) must be invertible ? Thanks :)

Comment: @the8thone The OP defines a positive operator as a Hermitian one such that $P_T(x,y)>0$ for all $x,y$. While some people are used to call this *strictly* positive, it's simply called positive in the OP. Regardless of the name, it's invertible. As for the proof of the problem statement (in either direction), we have: $U$ is unitary w.r.t. $P_T$ **iff** $P_T(Ux,Uy)=P_T(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ **iff** $\langle TUx,Uy\rangle = \langle Tx,y\rangle$ for all $x,y$ **iff** $\langle U^\ast TUx,y\rangle = \langle Tx,y\rangle$ for all $x,y$ **iff** $U^\ast TU=T$.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks ! it was really a one-liner :)